# What are my manual override options for Intelectron 861K motion detector?

Tags: electrical

I'd like to have a "manual override" option for the Intelectron 861K motion detector I'm installing, but I don't have the instructions. It seems like there's no manual override switch located on the light itself. I've seen wiring diagrams like this one below. But I've also heard that many motion detectors have this built in (flipping the wall switch off/on in a certain pattern). On the back of the box it mentions this option as well, but I'm not sure what they mean. I haven't been able to find information specific to this model online. Does anyone know if there is a "built-in" option? If not, what's the best way to wire this manual override option?

[image: wiring diagram]
[image: back of box]

Answer (score 0):

Without looking for your particular model's instructions, many such lights have a manual override "built-in" by just flipping the power to them quickly - on-off-on within some time (that varies - might be as short as 5 seconds or as long as 30 seconds.)

Comment: I was hoping for some information specific to the model.